# How to update local state when redux state is updated(react-redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have state that is managed inside a component.
And I'm using data from other component by storing them into the redux store.
However, at the end, i'm trying to collect all the data to make an api call.

```
const [projectData, setProjectData] = useState({})
const { userData } = useSelector((state) => state.userManage);
useEffect(() => {
    let newUsers = userData.map((x,i)=>({user_id:x.user_id, sub_user_id:x.sub_user_id}))
    setProjectState((state) =>({...state, users:newUsers}))
  }, [userData ]);


// this is handler 
const handleClick = () =>{
   dispatch(action.createProject(projectData));
}
```

I'm trying to update local state whenever the data i'm subscribing is changing.
Somehow it doesn't update correctly. When I don't use 'map' function and just

```
setProjectState((state) =>({...state, users: userData})) <= This works.
```

But it copys everything inside of userData,
so I'm using map function to pick specific data, not all data. but it is not working.

for example:

```
//redux store state
userData={user_id: 0, sub_id: [1,2,3], useless:"sda", useless2:"asd" }
```

I want to update and add local state only with user_id and sub_id

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works just fine, maybe you can provide an example that demonstrates your problem assuming you meant setProjectData instead of setProjectState:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const initialState = {
  userData: [],
};
//action types
const ADD = 'ADD';
//action creators
const userid = ((id) => () => id++)(1);
const sub = ((id) => () => id++)(1);
const add = () => ({
  type: ADD,
  payload: {
    user_id: userid(),
    sub_user_id: sub(),
    other: 'not used',
  },
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === ADD) {
    return {
      ...state,
      userData: [payload, ...state.userData],
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectUserData = (state) => state.userData;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);

const UserList = () => {
  const [projectData, setProjectData] = useState({});
  const userData = useSelector(selectUserData);
  useEffect(() => {
    let newUsers = userData.map((x, i) => ({
      user_id: x.user_id,
      sub_user_id: x.sub_user_id,
    }));
    setProjectData((state) => ({
      ...state,
      users: newUsers,
    }));
  }, [userData]);
  return (
    <div>
      userData:
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(userData, undefined, 2)}</pre>
      projectData:
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(projectData, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(add())}>
        add data
      </button>
      <UserList />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

However; instead of copying the data it would be best to just write a selector to get the data the way you want it:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { createSelector } = Reselect;

const initialState = {
  userData: [],
};
//action types
const ADD = 'ADD';
//action creators
const userid = ((id) => () => id++)(1);
const sub = ((id) => () => id++)(1);
const add = () => ({
  type: ADD,
  payload: {
    user_id: userid(),
    sub_user_id: sub(),
    other: 'not used',
  },
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === ADD) {
    return {
      ...state,
      userData: [payload, ...state.userData],
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectUserData = (state) => state.userData;
const selectProjectData = createSelector(
  [selectUserData], //re use selectUserData
  (userData) =>
    //modify user data to project data
    userData.map((x, i) => ({
      user_id: x.user_id,
      sub_user_id: x.sub_user_id,
    }))
);
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);

const UserList = () => {
  //no state, no effect, just select the way you want it
  const projectData = useSelector(selectProjectData);
  //if you want userData as well you can select that too
  // const userData = useSelector(selectUserData)
  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(projectData, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(add())}>
        add data
      </button>
      <UserList />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```